# OpenGL : How to use glMapBuffer with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

I'm trying to use glMapBuffer with a QOpenGLWidget but I can't find it. Here are my included files:

```
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QOpenGLTexture>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <QGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLShader>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix QOpenGL and QGL (remove QGLFunctions and so the old, deprecated OpenGL module in your project configuration). You don't need to include gl.h and glext.h.

You included QOpenGLBuffer. The method [map()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglbuffer.html#map) encapsulates glMapBuffer:

```
// creation

QOpenGLBuffer buffer = new QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
buffer->create();

// allocation

buffer->bind();

buffer->allocate(size_of_the_buffer);

buffer->release();

// update

buffer->bind();

void* buffer_data = buffer->map(QOpenGLBuffer::WriteOnly);

memcpy(buffer_data, your_data_to_copy, size_of_your_data_to_copy);

buffer->unmap();

buffer->release();
```

Comment: the map() method works for QOpenGLBuffer object, except that I'm using glBuffer for my VBOs. I would need to change it and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: A VBO is an OpenGL buffer like an other: use a QOpenGLBuffer to manage it. I edit my answer with an example

Comment: Ok, it's better with your example but I still have questions. What is the equivalent of glBufferSubData in your example ? Do in need to update it already for the first data transfer ? And how will it work with glVertexAttribPointer ? How can I manipulate the offset, since I'm passing Vertex and Texture coordonates data in my buffer.

Comment: For an equivalent to glBufferSubData, you can use [write()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglbuffer.html#write). You can use an [overload to allocate()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglbuffer.html#allocate) for first data transfer. glVertexAttribPointer, which should be used through [QOpenGLShaderProgram](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglshaderprogram.html#setAttributeArray), has a stride parameter if the data are interleaved. The offset is implicitly given by the "address" of the values